# link to # id not landing correctly

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, margin

I have a link on homepage to id. I have a fixed navigation, so I add "scroll-margin-top" to that link, so it wouldn't land behind the navigation, and it works ok. But when i go to that id link from another page, it disregards that "scroll-margin-top" ,  and  lands my section under the navigation.
How can i solve this?

```
<a href="#column" 
<span id="column"> text </span>
```

I tried "scroll-margin-top"

Answer (score 1):

It's probably caused because your "scroll-margin-top" uses some JavaScript/JQuery function to scroll to the element with a specific offset.

When you navigate from another page to your element with this anchor (id/#) so it's the default browser behavior that it navigates directly to the element.

I'd propose setting the element's id to some wrapper element and giving that element some top padding at the height of the navigation or higher.

```html
<a href="#column">link</a>
<div id="column" style="padding-top:80px;"> 
<span> text </span>
</div>
```

Another solution is using a smooth scroll written in JavaScript. This function has to be loaded on dom/window ready and then to navigate to the element.
E.g.

```js
$([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
    }, 2000);
```